# How To Reconnect to Tcp server from tcp client upon connection failure

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, tcp, tcpclient

I have a server, that sends some data in a very irregular periods of time and sends heartbeats for every 30 seconds of ideal time.

I wrote a TCP client to connect to that server and read data. It works OK, however when something is wrong with the network and server becomes unavailable i need to do the following actions.

when connection fails between client and server i need to try to reconnect to the server (repeat this process for three times with 30 seconds interval if server is not available after the interval, on successful re-connection i need to  continue working the process else i need to display message that server not available.)

how can i achieve this? please help me. here's my code.

```
private void ServiceMethod(string Port, string Host)
    {
        try
        {

            //create a new client socket ...
            m_socClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            String szIPSelected = Host;
            String szPort = Port;
            int alPort = System.Convert.ToInt16(szPort, 10);

            System.Net.IPAddress remoteIPAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(szIPSelected);
            System.Net.IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(remoteIPAddress, alPort);
            //m_socClient = new Socket(remoteEndPoint.Address.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            m_socClient.BeginConnect(remoteEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            //Code To Handle Exception
                        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }

    public void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        try
        {
            Object objData = "Client Connected";
            byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(objData.ToString());
            m_socClient.Send(byData);
            TraceService("client Connected at " + m_socClient.RemoteEndPoint);
            m_socClient.EndConnect(asyn);

            WaitForData(m_socClient);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "1", "\n OnClientConnection: Socket has been closed\n");
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            // MessageBox.Show(se.Message);

        }

    }


    public class CSocketPacket
    {
        public System.Net.Sockets.Socket thisSocket;
        public byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[100];
    }

    public void WaitForData(System.Net.Sockets.Socket soc)
    {
        try
        {
            if (pfnWorkerCallBack == null)
            {
                pfnWorkerCallBack = new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived);
            }
            CSocketPacket theSocPkt = new CSocketPacket();
            theSocPkt.thisSocket = soc;
            // now start to listen for any data...
            soc.BeginReceive(theSocPkt.dataBuffer, 0, theSocPkt.dataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, pfnWorkerCallBack, theSocPkt);
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
        }

    }

    public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        try
        {
            CSocketPacket theSockId = (CSocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;
            //end receive...
            int iRx = 0;
            iRx = theSockId.thisSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
            char[] chars = new char[iRx + 1];
            System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
            int charLen = d.GetChars(theSockId.dataBuffer, 0, iRx, chars, 0);


                    ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                    response = System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32("6", 16)).ToString();
                    m_socClient.Send(asen.GetBytes(response));



        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "1", "\nOnDataReceived: Socket has been closed\n");
            if (m_socClient.Connected)
            {
                WaitForData(m_socClient);

            }

        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {

            if (m_socClient.Connected)
            {
                WaitForData(m_socClient);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
           if (m_socClient.Connected)
            {
                WaitForData(m_socClient);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't have to implement this at all. TCP has already retry mechanisms in place.